# Route name same for inner part is not working

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.7

This is my route code. I have common route name status for each separate prefix but only uses that I have defined at last of the route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' =>'notice', 'namespace'=>'Admin'], function(){ 
     Route::post('/status','NoticeController@status')->name('status')->middleware('auth');
});
Route::group(['prefix' =>'facility', 'namespace'=>'Admin'], function(){
     Route::post('/status','FacilityController@status')->name('status')->middleware('auth');
});
Route::group(['prefix' =>'award', 'namespace'=>'Admin'], function(){
     Route::post('/status','AwardController@status')->name('status')->middleware('auth');         
});
```

### This is a common js file:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.status').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{route('status')}}",
      method: 'post',
      data: { id: id, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}' },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(id);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Route name in Laravel is unique

Route Name Prefixes

The name method may be used to prefix each route name in the group with a given string. For example, you may want to prefix all of the grouped route's names with admin. The given string is prefixed to the route name exactly as it is specified, so we will be sure to provide the trailing  `.` character in the prefix
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-prefixes

```
Route::name('notice')->group(['prefix' =>'notice', 'namespace'=>'Admin'], function(){ 
     Route::post('/status','NoticeController@status')->name('status')->middleware('auth');
});
Route::name('facility')->group(['prefix' =>'facility', 'namespace'=>'Admin'], function(){
     Route::post('/status','FacilityController@status')->name('status')->middleware('auth');
});
Route::name('award')->group(['prefix' =>'award', 'namespace'=>'Admin'], function(){
     Route::post('/status','AwardController@status')->name('status')->middleware('auth');         
});
```

And in your JS section use 
`{{ route('award.status') }}`

Comment: if I write {{ route('award.status') }} then it works only for award.
I need It also for other two routes at the same JS

Comment: You can make if condition

Comment: how can i apply if condition any suggestion

Comment: Say you have column name `account_type` in your `users` table  then use `{{ route(Auth::user()->account_type.'.status') }}` so account type refer to `award`, `facility` or `notice`